# Magento dashboard not updating

Tags: magento-1.9, dashboard

Since now i see a problem on a dashboard from our client, it is showing the amount of orders but not the total value (price) of the orders... That is stopped since i think 2 weeks.

The total value stays on 5.949,90 but only the amount of orders is counting not the value of it.

Comment: You should refresh statistics

Comment: how can i do that? :)

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

To refresh sales report statistics:

```
1.  On the Admin menu, select Reports > Refresh Statistics.
2.  In the list, select the checkbox of each report that needs to be refreshed.
3.  Set the Actions control to one of the following:

Refresh Lifetime Statistics
Refresh Statistics for the Last Day

4.  When complete, click the Submit button.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That doesn't does the trick :( I just keep seeing information like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bpQPA.png

Comment: chk this https://pratikkhamar.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/magento-programmatically-refresh-statistics/